# ticks on scatter plots

Tags: python, scatter-plot

This may be a very simple question as I already plot so many scattered plots.

I have a file with multiple columns, I want to plot a scatter plot with two columns(contains decimals values). I used different Xlim and Ylims but it does not work. Would you please have a look that where I'm repeating a mistake? It should be limited within Xlim (104,105) and Ylim (29,30).  Thanks  [image]

```
data example:
104.4990 29.3803
104.482 29.38342
104.480 29.4245
104.4900 29.4010
104.4899 29.39437
104.4968 29.3899
104.4902 29.38032
104.5358 29.4033
104.486 29.37633
104.4940 29.38172
104.4793 29.3925
104.5393 29.40455


plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(10,8), 'figure.dpi':100})
for cluster in os.listdir(data):
    if cluster.endswith("BXC.txt"):
        clust=os.path.join(data,cluster)
        with open (clust, "r") as myfile:
            for line in myfile:
                l= line.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
                evla=l[4][:-10]
                evlo=l[5][:-10]
                plt.scatter(evlo, evla)
            plt.show()
```

Comment: I solved it. The only problem was this to change the Evla and evlo to float numbers. :)